# How do you add values inside a variable together in Linux Bash?

Tags: linux

For example, variable number has 156985630. How do I add these numbers together and return another variable with the sum?

Answer (score 0):

With pure bash:

```
nums=156985630
for ((i=1;i<${#nums};i++));do
    sum=$[sum+${nums:$i:1}]
done
echo sum=$sum
```

With external programs:

```
echo $nums|grep -o .|paste -sd+|bc
```